# Boy meets girl in an apartment complex playground

Tags: identify-this-movie

What is the name of this film?

A boy meets a girl in an apartment complex playground. It's cold, snow on the ground, and she might be smoking. The boy is shy and a loner. The girl isn't what she seems. Maybe a vampire or werewolf.

The girl might be living with her father. The boy takes the girl to an old basement room in the building that he has turned into a secret hideaway.

I remember scenes where the boy is in his bedroom listening to noises from her apartment. Her father wants her to stay inside or something, but she wants to be free. The father might not be her real father. He might have to go out and kill people for her to survive.

I don't remember much more about the film. Except that in the end something happens in the girl's apartment. Someone is killed in the bathroom. There is a lot of blood. She ends up having to leave.

The film was released in the last 10 years (maybe less).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like the 2008 Swedish film [Let the Right One In](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1139797/).  There was also a Hollywood remake in 2010 called [Let Me In](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1228987/), so you may have seen that.

Comment: +1 Thanks! That is the film. I watched the 2010 one, but now I want to watch the 2008 one with subtitles :)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini You're welcome.  I haven't seen the remake yet, but the original is *extremely* well done.  I'd highly recommend it to anyone who likes scary movies.